Download .apk and show install prompt in React Native Expo
I have an app that is not to be published on Playstore (as per the client's requirement). So I want the updated .apk to be downloaded on the phone and the install prompt to be shown with Expo.
Here's my sample code:
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import { startActivityAsync } from 'expo-intent-launcher';

const downloadUpdate = async() => {
    console.log("<====================================================>")
    const downloadResumable = FileSystem.createDownloadResumable(
      "https://url.in/appName.apk",
      FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'appName' + versionID +'.apk',
      {},
      callback
    );
    const callback = downloadProgress => {
      const progress = downloadProgress.totalBytesWritten / downloadProgress.totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
      console.log(progress)
    };

    const { uri } = await downloadResumable.downloadAsync();
    console.log('Finished downloading to ', uri);
    
    const contentUri = await FileSystem.getContentUriAsync(uri);
    console.log('content URI ', contentUri);
    try {

      let data = await startActivityAsync('android.intent.action.VIEW', { data: contentUri, flags: 1, type: 'application/vnd.android.package-archive' });
      console.log(data)
    } catch (error) {}

}

But this returns as {"resultCode": 0}
